# Swift: Pointers to Struct vs Classes

Tags: swift, class, struct

I understand that generally `structs` in `swift` are `pass-by-value`. I use a `struct` for `encapsulating` a few bits of information add the `struct` to a set and later change small bits of its values. However; I seemed to have fallen into an issue whereby the `structs` are not updating correctly even though I have sprinkled the keyword `inout` everywhere the parameter requires a `struct`. My gut instinct was to allocate memory for the `struct` and refer to it in the set by it's `pointer`. Would it make sense to simply use a `class` even though all I need is a list of values that can change.

Comment: Code please! Are they `var`s in the structs?

Comment: It's kind of spread out the code the struct has around 10 variables marked 'var' though yes since it is a requirement to change these fields. Once source of possible issue is that I also add them to a set and update them at a later time, I will attempt to use create a base case but I use a lot of Completion handlers since I have to wait for the query to update the database and return. One issue I have found when i println is that when returned from the completion handler and sent as a variable to another job the values are not updated in the set

Comment: Re your set usage - the values in the set will not ever be the same "instance" ('cos they're values) as the ones you put into the set or access from the set to modify. Your only hope in the set scenario is to access them, delete original from set and re-add them.

Comment: At least 200 structs in the set are changed twice every call to the database and each are connected as references to other parts of the application as references. Which is why I asked even though classes are slower would it make more sense to simply use classes or pointers to struct to prevent the requirement of unnecessarily removing and re-adding the struct to the sets and reconnecting each individually to the correct items.

Answer (score 1):

If you need reference semantics, then absolutely use a class. If you want to be able to modify your object both in a data structure as well as other places, a class is what you need. It is perfectly reasonable to use a class just to get reference semantics.

Also so you know, inout on a function parameter does not actually mean pass by reference. What is actually happening is a copy of your struct is made by the function. This copy is then modified in the function and later copied back to the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, I can't see what you're doing wrong, but it works for me - Playground minimal example:

```
struct Grimxn {
    var first: Int
    var second: Int
}

func modify(inout v: Grimxn) {
    v.first++
    v.second--
}

var a = Grimxn(first: 1, second: 2)
print("\(a)") // "Grimxn(first: 1, second: 2)\n"
modify(&a)
print("\(a)") // "Grimxn(first: 2, second: 1)\n" - as required?
```

I certainly wouldn't want to use pointers - why do that in Swift - use C!